# Connect to WebDAV server with Nautilus 3.18

Tags: nautilus, webdav, synology

I want to access to my files stored in my Synology NAS using WebDAV. I enabled the WebDAV server on the NAS and I can establish a working connection in the CLI using `cadaver`. However, I want to be able to browse my files using Nautilus. I use Archlinux.

Usually, to access a distant server, I go to the “Other locations” page and select the one I want:

[image: Nautilus 3.18 other locations]

For WebDAV, I have two choices:

- “alta-plana (dav+sd)” for WebDAV through HTTP,
- “alta-plana (davs+sd)” for WebDAV through HTTPS.

“alta-plana” is the name of my NAS. When I click on the lines, I always get an error (the same for the two lines):

```
**Impossible to access location**
Error resolving _webdav._tcp service "alta-plana" on domain "local". One or more TXT records are missing. Keys required: "u".
```

Using the text field at the bottom of the window, I get different behaviours:

- dav://alta-plana seems to do nothing except refreshing the window,
- davs://alta-plana shows a Gnome Shell dialog box to ask me to accept or not the synology.com certificate and clicking “Yes” or “No” does absolutely nothing (not even refreshing the window).

All information I could find about using WebDAV with Nautilus mention the now deleted dialog to connect distant servers so it is impossible to follow what it is said. Besides, I do not understand what exactly is missing.

So, is there a way to access my files stored on my NAS through WebDAV with Nautilus 3.18 or, alternatively, will it be possible with the 3.20 version that came out today?